# Update snackbar state from parent component

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to dismiss the snack bar after the user presses ok or after the duration. I tried passing an extra variable to the component and changing state but it does not work. Here is my code for the LogIn page that uses the snackbar component that renders only after a bad login request , its not the whole code:

```
 const [error, setError] = React.useState(false);
  const [username, setUsername] = React.useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = React.useState('');

  const [visible, setVisible] = React.useState(false);

  /* const form = createForm(data); */
  return (
    <View style={Style.container}>
      {error && (
        <View style={{width: '30%', height: '10%'}}>
          <Snack_alert
            message={'Wrong username or password!'}
            textcolor={'white'}
            btn_color={'white'}
            snack_color={'red'}
            dismiss={() => {
              setVisible(false);
            }}
          />
        </View>
      )}
```

and here is the child component:

```
export default function Snack_alert({

  message,
  textcolor,
  btn_color,
  snack_color,
  dismiss

}) {
  return (
    <Snackbar
      visible={true}
      onDismiss={() => {
        {
        dismiss
        }
      }}
      duration={2500}
      theme={{
        colors: {
          surface: textcolor,
          accent: btn_color,
          onSurface: snack_color,
        },
      }}
      //surface: text color , accent: undo color, onSurface: snackbar color
      action={{
        label: 'Ok',
        onPress: () => {
          {
           dismiss
          }
        },
      }}>
      {message}
    </Snackbar>
  );
}
```

Also later in my code I update the setError to true so that I can render the snackbar , I am unsure if that causes any problems.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you pass the prop `dismiss` to the `Snack_alert` component from the parent container is correct. The prop `dismiss` holds a function. Thus,

```js
onDismiss={() => {
    {
        dismiss
    }
}}
```

is basically the same as writing

```js
function dismiss() {
    setVisible(false)
}

function onDismiss() {
  {
    dismiss
  }
}
```

Let us log what will happen if we call `onDismiss()`. This yields

```js
undefined
```

since `onDismiss`does not return anything. Let us return `dismiss` and see what will happen.

```js
function onDismiss() {
  {
    return dismiss
  }
}
```

If we call `onDismiss` again it yields the following output.

```js
function dismiss() {
    setVisible(false);
}
```

The function `dismiss` is now correctly returned, but it is not called. This is fine if you know that the `Snackbar` component will internally do something like this.

```js
const foo = onDismiss()
foo()
```

The constant `foo` gets assigned the return value of the function `onDismiss` which is the function `dismiss` that we have passed as a prop. We can call `dismiss` by calling `foo`. This will correctly set the visible state to `false`. Notice that it is more convenient to write

```js
onDismiss={dismiss}
```

since then the prop `onDismiss` gets the prop `dismiss` assigned which is the function `dismiss` that we have passed earlier. Thus, instead of calling `onDismiss` as a function in order to retrieve `dismiss`, the `Snackbar` container can now directly call `onDismiss()` and this will call `dismiss()`.

My last comment is how the `Snackbar` component works. It expects the following.

```js
<Snackbar
  visible={visible}
  onDismiss={() => setVisible(false)}
  ...
/>
```

Thus, `onDismiss` is a function that when called sets the `visible` state of the component. Hence, you need to fix two things.

1. Change the way you are passing the function `dismiss`.
2. Pass the visible state to `Snack_alert` from the parent container.

By knowing this, we can construct a working version of your code as follows.

```js
onst [error, setError] = React.useState(false);
  const [username, setUsername] = React.useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = React.useState('');

  const [visible, setVisible] = React.useState(false);

  /* const form = createForm(data); */
  return (
    <View style={Style.container}>
      {error && (
        <View style={{width: '30%', height: '10%'}}>
          <Snack_alert
            message={'Wrong username or password!'}
            textcolor={'white'}
            btn_color={'white'}
            snack_color={'red'}
            visible={visible}
            dismiss={() => {
              setVisible(false);
            }}
          />
        </View>
      )}


...

export default function Snack_alert({

  message,
  textcolor,
  btn_color,
  snack_color,
  dismiss,
  visible

}) {
  return (
    <Snackbar
      visible={visible}
      onDismiss={dismiss}
      duration={2500}
      theme={{
        colors: {
          surface: textcolor,
          accent: btn_color,
          onSurface: snack_color,
        },
      }}
      //surface: text color , accent: undo color, onSurface: snackbar color
      action={{
        label: 'Ok',
        onPress: dismiss,
      }}>
      {message}
    </Snackbar>
  );
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer , I know completly understood it , it seems I have a new problem considering Ux now , everything seems to work but the snackbar is no longer visible when I receive a bad request, it is caused by Visible prop

Comment: nevermind , i fixed it , it was the way i handled setError. Thanks again for your informative answer

Answer (score 1):

> action={{
> label: 'Ok',
> onPress: () => {
> {
> dismiss
> }
> },
> }}

You don't call the dismiss-function.
Either add parenthesis:

```
onPress: () => {
  dismiss()
}
```

Or just pass the function directly:

```
onPress: dismiss
```

Comment: dismiss is a variable I pass to the child component updating the parent's state.
dismiss={() => {
              setVisible(false);
            }}

Comment: That's right but dismiss is also a function you need to call.
Incidentally, my second example is exactly what David Scholz suggested